# How can I configure debug or "run without debugging" in CMake Tools (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Is there a way to configure what happens when I press "Launch selected target without debugging" command in CMakeTools in VSCode?

[image]

My problem is that the target is launched but it doesn't pick up the config file I specified in my launch.json for the Debug configuration:

*launch.json:*

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [
                "/home/<myuser>/dev/my_api_conf.ini"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
            "initCommands": [   "command source ${workspaceRoot}/.lldbinit"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cmake.debugConfig` setting ([docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings)). I think it uses the same schema as the `cppdbg` launch configuration type. You can use it in your workspace .vscode/settings.json file, or your user settings.json file. I noticed this setting thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/924#issuecomment-845539774) in a historically related issue ticket. For some reason, at the time of this writing, this setting is not mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md. I'm not sure if anything from this applies to running *without* debugging, but it's definitely used with the `CMake: Debug` command / action.

If you want to use your launch config, then you will have to use the keyboard shortcut / command / button for running with that launch config- not the button provided by CMake Tools. Ex. the button in the Run and Debug View, or the `Debug: Start Without Debugging` command in the command palette (instead of the `CMake: Run Without Debugging` command).

Comment: Good to know thank you. Is there by any chance an opportunity to link cmake.debugConfig to launch json via this settings entry?

Comment: @glades not sure. docs on the subject [seem to be quite out of date right now](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/3360) and I'm not in the mood for digging into the source code right now. What exactly do you mean by "link cmake.debugConfig to launch json"?

Comment: Well just having cmake.debugConfig invoke the configuration present in launch.json so I don't have to repeat it all the time.

Comment: @glades, if avoiding repetition is your goal, why not just put the cmake.debugConfig in your user settings instead of workspace settings?